# Combining columns without losing information of their interaction in pandas?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, data-science

This is a classification task. This is the format of the data set:

[image]

The first row contains the labels for the patients.

I initially wanted to transpose the table to have patient IDs as an index but I am not sure how to get columns region, position, and gene into one column.

If I just combined the columns to create a column name, I feel a lot of information is lost during modeling, since for eg Gene 1 in position 78 region 4 and position 74 and region 5  might behave the same way.
So the information of the interaction between these columns might be lost if I were to just combine the columns.

Can someone suggest how can I get the patient IDs as my index and yet retain all the information about these column interactions for my statistical analysis?

Comment: whichever index you decide on, can you not keep the data in the main table? so `df.set_index( [...], drop=False )` for instance?

Comment: I want the index to be the patient numbers. And I want to figure out a way to make the region, position and gene as the column names without loosing the interaction between them